# "Highest" level of illegal move

Tags: history, grandmaster, illegal-move, super-grandmaster

For example, was a GM ever caught on an illegal move? Of course, only standard time control (everybody still remembers Carlsen-Inarkiev, but that was a blitz game) and after FIDE codification of chess rules ("in my home town, we castle this way" :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another illegal move was made by in a game Zagrebelny Sergey vs Kayumov Dmitry

```
[Title "Zagrebelny Sergey vs Kayumov Dmitry (1992)"]
[fen ""]
1. e4 c5 2. Nf3 d6 3. d4 cxd4 4. Nxd4 Nf6 5. Nc3 a6 6. Be3 e5 7. Nb3 Be6 8. f4
Ng4 9. Bd2 exf4 10. Bxf4 Nc6 11. Qd2 Be7 12. O-O-O O-O 13. Kb1 Rc8 14. Nd5 Bxd5
15. exd5 Nce5 16. h3 Nf6 17. g4 Re8 18. g5 Nh5 19. h4 Nxf4 20. Qxf4 g6 21. Nd2
f5 22. gxf6 Bxf6 23. Bh3 Rc7 24. Ne4 Rf8 25. h5 g5 26. Qf5 Kh8 27. Rdf1 Rcf7 28.
Qe6 Nc4 29. Nxg5 Re7 30. Qxf6+ Rxf6 31. Rxf6 Re1+ 32. Rxe1 Qxf6 0-1
```

This is what was on the scoresheet, but what actually happened was the below. No one noticed due to both players being low on time.

```
[Title "Zagrebelny Sergey vs Kayumov Dmitry (1992)"]
[fen ""]
1. e4 c5 2. Nf3 d6 3. d4 cxd4 4. Nxd4 Nf6 5. Nc3 a6 6. Be3 e5 7. Nb3 Be6 8. f4
Ng4 9. Bd2 exf4 10. Bxf4 Nc6 11. Qd2 Be7 12. O-O-O O-O 13. Kb1 Rc8 14. Nd5 Bxd5
15. exd5 Nce5 16. h3 Nf6 17. g4 Re8 18. g5 Nh5 19. h4 Nxf4 20. Qxf4 g6 21. Nd2
f5 22. gxf6 Bxf6 23. Bh3 Rc7 24. Ne4 Rf8 25. h5 g5 26. Qf5 Kh8 27. Rdf1 Rcf7 28.
Qe6 Nc4 29. Nxg5 Re7 30. Rxf6 Rxf6 31. Qxf6+ 0-1
```

[Website article](https://www.chess.com/article/view/the-illegal-move-that-wrecked-a-chess-career)

Comment: In the absence of a 'compare these two games' function, a hint as to where the illegality occurred would help a lot.

Comment: scoresheets:
30. Qxf6+ Rxf6 31. Rxf6 Re1+ 32. Rxe1 Qxf6 0-1.

reality on board:
30. Rxf6 Rxf6 31. Qxf6+ 0-1.

Did the players both make up 3 plies after White's 31st? No: rather, the players played 31 ... Re1+ 32. Rxe1 Qxf6, neither noticing that 31 ... Re1+ 32. Rxe1 were illegal because wQf6 was checking bKh8. Both players were in time trouble, & FIDE's Laws allow players in time trouble to stop recording their moves. But seemingly both players put White's Qxf6+ & Rxf6 on their scoresheets in the wrong order in order to make it look as if no illegal move had happened.

Answer (score 2):

Garry Kasparov (who else?) pushed a pawn to the 8th rank in time trouble against Karpov and pressed the clock without replacing the pawn with a queen. Karpov eventually lost on time in a losing position despite getting an additional 2 minutes for the illegal move.

```
[Title "Anatoly Karpov vs Garry Kasparov Linares (1993)"]

[fen ""]
1. d4 Nf6 2. c4 g6 3. Nc3 Bg7 4. e4 d6 5. f3 O-O 6. Be3 e5 7. Nge2 c6 8. Qd2 Nbd7 9. Rd1 a6 10. dxe5 Nxe5 11. b3 b5 12. cxb5 axb5 13. Qxd6 Nfd7 14. f4 b4 15. Nb1 Ng4 16. Bd4 Bxd4 17. Qxd4 Rxa2 18. h3 c5 19. Qg1 Ngf6 20. e5 Ne4 21. h4 c4 22. Nc1 c3 23. Nxa2 c2 24. Qd4 cxd1=Q+ 25. Kxd1 Ndc5 26. Qxd8 Rxd8+ 27. Kc2 Nf2 0-1
```

See the match on [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VZYTymhN-Tc).

Answer (score 1):

Examples of illegal castling are fairly common.  See for example:

https://www.chess.com/article/view/do-grandmasters-know-the-rules-of-chess